# How to update a field with different values based on previous value in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to update a field with a new value depending on its previous value. E.g: if field 'set' values are either 'aaa' or 'bbb', I want to provide a list of new values so that, say, 'aaa' becomes 'ccc' and 'bbb' becomes 'ddd'.

This query is were I am stuck:

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {"set.keyword": ["aaa", "bbb"]}
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.set = 'ccc'; ctx._source.set = 'ddd';"
  }
}
```

Instead of getting different updated values ('ccc' or 'ddd' depending on which was the previous value), all values are updated to 'ddd'. I suspect it is updating all values twice.

- Using Val's query below, I get the following output:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "ctx._source.set = ctx._source.set.stream().map(elem -> {\n         ",
          "                                 ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "       ctx._source.set = ctx._source.set.stream().map(elem -> {\n         if (params[elem] != null) {\n           return params[elem];\n         } else {\n           return elem;\n         }\n       }).collect(Collectors.toList());",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "ctx._source.set = ctx._source.set.stream().map(elem -> {\n         ",
      "                                 ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "       ctx._source.set = ctx._source.set.stream().map(elem -> {\n         if (params[elem] != null) {\n           return params[elem];\n         } else {\n           return elem;\n         }\n       }).collect(Collectors.toList());",
    "lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Unable to find dynamic method [stream] with [0] arguments for class [java.lang.String]."
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

- Mapping does not explicitly mention 'set' field:

```
    MY_MAPPING = '''{
                    "mappings": {
                        "data_type": {
                            "properties": {
                                "delivered": {
                                    "type": "date",
                                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                                },
                                "requested": {
                                    "type": "date",
                                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                                },
                                "location": {
                                    "type": "geo_point"
                                }                            

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }'''
```

Taking a look at my index, I have 'set' as a searchable string and 'set.keyword', also a string, that is searchable and aggregatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {"set.keyword": ["aaa", "bbb"]}
  },
  "script": {
    "source": """
       def currentSet = ctx._source.set;
       ctx._source.set = (params[currentSet] != null) ? params[currentSet] : currentSet;
    """,
    "params": {
      "aaa": "ccc",
      "bbb": "ddd"
    }
  }
}
```

In other terms, the script will iterate over the `set` array and for each element, it will return whatever new value is in the params hash for a given old value, or the old value itself if there's no new value.

If your `set` is `["aaa", "bbb", "xxx"]` then after updating your index, it would contain `["ccc", "ddd", "xxx"]`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately is doesn't work. I'll update the question, as the output is too long to be postes as a comment

Comment: Can you also share your index mapping please?

Comment: Oh, `set` is a string, not an array of course, my bad... I've updated my answer and the solution is simpler.